# How do I modify and append to SQL tables using Excel VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, ado, adodb

I have some VBA I am wanting to use to update and add data to a table on an SQL server. I have been muddling through with limited knowledge of this functionality within VBA all day, searching various sites and not really getting any answers to make things click into place and not getting any response when posting it elsewhere. Hopefully I can get this solved here.

So, I have the following code that I have cobbled together:

```
Sub connectsqlserver()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim recset As ADODB.Recordset
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim msgstrng As String
Dim newstring As String
 If conn.State <> 0 Then
 conn.Close
 End If
 With conn
    .ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};server=sage500;Database=CS3Live;Uid=sa;Pwd=pass; ReadOnly=False;"""
    .ConnectionTimeout = 5
    .Open
  End With
 recset.Open Source:="custinfosheetdata", ActiveConnection:=conn, CursorType:=adOpenKeyset, LockType:=adLockOptimistic
 
 
 If Sheets("Changes").Range("A1").Value <> 0 Then
 For i = 1 To Sheets("Changes").Range("A1").Value
    recset.Find "Col2 = " & Sheets("Changes").Cells(2, i + 2) 'find the value in B from B3 onwards
    'Do something
 Next i
 Sheets("Changes").Rows("3:" & i + 2).Delete xlUp
 Else
 i = 0
 End If
 If Sheets("New").Range("A1").Value <> 0 Then
 For j = 1 To Sheets("New").Range("A1").Value
    newstring = ""
    For k = 1 To 38
    If k = 38 Then
    newstring = newstring & "'" & Cells(j + 2, k).Value & "'"
    Else
    newstring = newstring & "'" & Cells(j + 2, k).Value & "', "
    newstring = Format(newstring, "")
    End If
    Next k
    Debug.Print (newstring)
    With recset
    .AddNew (newstring)
    .Update
    End With
 Next j
 Sheets("New").Rows("3:" & j + 2).Delete xlUp
 Else
 j = 0
 End If
 recset.Close
 conn.Close
 If i = 0 And j = 0 Then
 msgstring = "No Changes/New Data to add"
 Else
 If i = 0 And j <> 0 Then
 msgstring = "No Changes and " & j & " New Customers added"
 Else
 If i <> 0 And j = 0 Then
 msgstring = i & " Changes and no New Customers added"
 Else
 msgstring = i & " Changes and " & j & " New Customers added"
 End If
 End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Part 1: This currently throws out an error at "With recset.AddNew..." (3001) saying that arguments are of the wrong type. The table it is going to is formatted as nvarchar(255) and all the data is formatted as text in the various fields so I am not entirely sure whats happening there.

Part 1 code:

```
If lastrow <> 0 Then
 For j = 1 To lastrow
    For k = 1 To lastfield
    If k = lastfield Then
    newstring = newstring & "'" & Cells(j + 2, k).Value & "'"
    Else
    newstring = newstring & "'" & Cells(j + 2, k).Value & "', "
    newstring = Format(newstring, "")
    End If
    Next k
    With recset
    .AddNew (newstring)
    .Update
    End With
 Next j
 End If
```

Part 2: As my knowledge of VBA for ADODB connections is awful at best, I cannot figure out how to continue once I have found the row I require, hence the "'Do something" line. What I need this to do is find the record matched from column B in the "Changes" excel table and then edit that row in the SQL table to match it. I can't figure out how to do this though.
Part 2 code:

```
 If lastrow <> 0 Then
 For i = 1 To lastrow
        recset.Find "Col2 = " & Sheets("Changes").Cells(2, i + 2) 'find the value in B from B3 onwards
' Do something
 Next i
     End If
```

**EDIT**: I have this from the debug.print which may help some people visualise this a bit more:

```
"23/07/13","TEST123","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test"
```

This is for a full line (so therefore the Field List should not be required as this is data for every column in the correct order).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Addnew takes two arguments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677536(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @mehow, I have modified it slightly to explain what I am getting at a bit better.

Comment: @LaymanCoder they are in fact optional, so one line should suffice. You only need to use two if you are updating one or two values and need to column match. I am replacing the entire row

FieldList-
Optional. A single name, or an array of names or ordinal positions of the fields in the new record.

Values-
Optional. A single value, or an array of values for the fields in the new record. If Fieldlist is an array, Values must also be an array with the same number of members; otherwise, an error occurs. The order of field names must match the order of field values in each array.

Comment: This is a monolithic piece of code where everything is mixed up together: extraction of data from cells, connecting to database, modifying Recordset, printing informational messages. I would suggest you to write functions and subroutines to do individual tasks and test each of these on their own. Doing otherwise will make your code difficult to maintain in the future.

Comment: The print messages are purely for my debugging needs right now and will be got rid of once it is working. The code itself is actually in different subs as it is in excel, but brought back together when it didnt work to make it more linear for easier debugging until I got to the root of the problem. Should people think it will be easier, I will cut the bits I dont need help with from the code. I just personally like to see the code as a whole to see exactly what it is meant to be doing.

Comment: Have done that now and added in part 1 code and part 2 code.

Comment: As the `AddNew` method takes two optional parameters - `FieldList` and `Values` - you need to use named arguments if you want to specify the `Values` parameter without specifying `FieldList`. This is as simple as `.AddNew Values:=aryValues`

Comment: Thanks, I did try that too but was getting issues with this for some reason. Ended up using a loop expression using both fieldlist and values, which I shall post up once I have done some more bug testing on it but it seems to work well from what limited sample data I had to test it with (it goes live on Monday at work, so will post it then)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will post this now actually instead of Monday or else I may forget.

Ended up being the neatest solution as working with arrays in this case seemed to fail a lot and they are a lot harder to debug. This at least made it a lot simpler.

Also, was good finding out that once you have found the row (my part 2 question), that it is in fact the same process as with .addnew (which was what I was not sure of)

```
With conn
    .ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};server=sage;Database=CS3Live;Uid=sa;Pwd=pass; ReadOnly=False;"""
    .Open
  End With
 recset.Open Source:="custinfosheetdata", ActiveConnection:=conn, CursorType:=adOpenKeyset, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

 If Sheets("Changes").Range("A1").Value <> 0 Then
    For i = 3 To LastRow
        With recset
            .Find "Col2 = " & "'" & Sheets("Changes").Range("B" & i) & "'"
            For k = 1 To 38
                strField = Sheets("Changes").Cells(2, k).Value
                varValue = Sheets("Changes").Cells(i, k).Value
                .Fields(strField).Value = varValue
            Next k
            .Update
        End With
    Next i
 Else
 i = 0
 End If

 If Sheets("New").Range("A1").Value <> 0 Then
     For j = 3 To LastRow
        With recset
           .AddNew
            For k = 1 To 38
                strField = Sheets("New").Cells(2, k).Value
                varValue = Sheets("New").Cells(j, k).Value
                .Fields(strField).Value = varValue
            Next k
            .Update
        End With
    Next j
 Else
 j = 0
 End If
... etc
```

So anyway, thanks to all that tried helping on here. I still cannot understand why arrays were not working though.

Answer (score 2):

From what you posted, I believe you've been trying to concatenate all the values into a string separated by ','. (correct me if I'm wrong)

This answer is only useful if you wanted to append new data, if you want to find a specific record in the database and update it then its a completely different story.

The "Add New" method takes in two arguments.

1. The list of fields in array format
2. The list of values in array format

Unless you have only one field or one value to add you should put them into array before using the "Add New" method.

A possible way of constructing the arrays:

```
For i = 0 to count_of_fields
    aryFields(i) = field_value
Next
For i = 0 to count_of_values
    aryValues(i) = value
Next
recset.AddNew aryFields,aryValues
recset.Update
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Yes thats right, I am concatenating in there. Appending New Data is what I am doing in that part. The code is in fact in two seperate parts. One doing changes, one doing new data to be appended. I shall try adding the fields to the data string I already have, but as I am setting a full line with the correct columns, it should not make a difference.

Comment: Afraid that makes no difference after adapting it to put in. Still getting an error.

Comment: +1 for your code. The other possibility would be to use parametrized Command objects.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181734 on how to create ADO parametrized commands.

Comment: Was thinking about using those earlier on, but assumed they would be slower (having to actually run outside of the VBA rather than natively) so was trying to avoid that if possible, but good to know it is a viable option.

Comment: As I said, you cannot put a concatenated string as the argument for the input. Let's say you have 5 values you have to put in all with value "Test". You need to create an array to hold that 5 values not a concatenated string.

something like:
Array("Test","Test","Test","Test","Test")

or 
Dim aryValue() as variant
Redim aryValue(4)
for i = 0 to 4
    aryValue(i) = "Test"
next

Comment: Been adapting this code more to fit my needs and still cannot get it working with or without the aryFields. Plus, I cannot do a debug.print on the full array to check it is structured properly so while the suggestion may be useful in some cases, for my purpose, this is not as useful as my original (if slightly longer) code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You may want to check the array using watch. put a line break before the upload line ("F9") and then right click on the variable aryFields or aryValue and click add to watch. You can then view all the values stored within